# Maintaining same recent colours list for WPF RadColorPicker in the application

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

I am looking for maintaining the same recent color list for all the RadColorPicker instances which we have in application. e. g. if user creates a custom color from one colorpicker (and colorEditor) control, user doesn't have to do the same for another color pickers. User should see the same color in recent colors for the all the color pickers.

I am trying to figure out, how to implement it. I see the property RecentColorsItemsSource, which could be of use here , but then, I am not able to get it working. I am trying to set sample colors using "RecentColorsItemsSource" property, but I am getting into a run time error. Following is the xaml code and the code behind code:

Xaml:

```
<telerik:RadColorPicker x:Name="myColorPicker" IsRecentColorsActive="True" RecentColorsItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyColors}" />
```

CodeBehind or ViewModel:

```
public partial class Window9 : Window
{
    public Window9()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        MyColors = new List<Color> { Colors.Red, Colors.Green };
    }

    private IEnumerable<Color> myColors;

    public IEnumerable<Color> MyColors
    {
        get { return myColors; }
        set { myColors = value; }
    }
}
```

but with this code I am getting this error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadColorSelector.BindRecentColorsPalette()
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadColorSelector.BindXamlElements()
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadColorSelector.OnApplyTemplate()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
```

Some help here would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You can set IsRecentColorsActive="True"

See this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/P_Telerik_Windows_Controls_RadColorPicker_IsRecentColorsActive.htm).

If you have to maintain the recent colors among multiple instances of color picker controls then you have to take advantage of [RecentColorsItemsSource Property](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/P_Telerik_Windows_Controls_RadColorPicker_RecentColorsItemsSource.htm). So basically you have to maintain the recent colors collection and bind the same collection to all the color pickers for which you want the recent colors to be shared.

Comment: That helps when we are using a single Color picker. Example of my scenario is, say we are using color picker in a color column of a grid, then recent color of the first row color picker won't be there for the second one and so on.

Comment: I explored the same too, but i am getting null reference exception while using it and I am not able to figure out where I am getting that. I am using this code to set this collection.

radColorPicker.RecentColorsItemsSource = new List<Color> { Colors.Red, Colors.Pink };

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but it might help anyone who come across the same issue like me.

I had some success using an `ObservableCollection<Color>` for the RecentColorsItemsSource.
Telerik probably casts RecentColorsItemsSource to ObservableCollection internally.

Try something like:

`...
       MyColors = new ObservableCollection<Color> { Colors.Red, Colors.Green };
...`